# Check for nil?, Blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model and for some reason I am trying to tell rails if there is nothing created then render add a new show link.

```
<% if @show != blank? %>
  <%= link_to 'Add a new show', new_show_path %></br>
<% else %>
 <%= render(:partial => 'shows/show', :locals => {:show => @profile.shows.last}) %>
<% end %>
```

It adds the *Add a new show* link but once a show is created I still only see the link and not the partial. If I create the show and put the render at top like so then I can see it but if i delete the show it returns an error.

I've tried these also

```
<% if @show.present? %>
 <%= render(:partial => 'shows/show', :locals => {:show => @profile.shows.last}) %>
<% else %>
 <%= link_to 'Add a new show', new_show_path %></br>
<% end %>


<% if @show.blank? %>
 <%= link_to 'Add a new show', new_show_path %></br>
<% else %>
 <%= render(:partial => 'shows/show', :locals => {:show => @profile.shows.last}) %>
<% end %>


<% if #{model} nil? %>
  <%= link_to 'Add a new show', new_show_path %></br>
<% else %>
  <%= render(:partial => 'shows/show', :locals => {:show => @profile.shows.last}) %>
<% end %>
```

and it seems to never give me what I am looking for on both ends. It ethiers shows me the link and nevers shows the partial once created or it shows the partial but when I delete it it gives me an error.

How can I tell rails that if there is no shows created to render the add new link and once there is a show created to render the partial?

Comment: try: `if defined? @show`

Comment: Have you tried `@show.nil?` (can't tell if that's what you mean by `#{model} nil?`

Comment: Yes have tried @show.nil? and by `#{model} nil?` if model name of any model is nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually filtering this by profile? It looks like you're rendering a page for the last show of a profile. (`@profile.shows.last`)

```
<% show = @profile.shows.last %>
<% if show.blank? %>
  <%= link_to 'Add a new show', new_show_path %>
  <br />
<% else %>
  <%= render 'shows/show', :show => show %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thank you also do i have to include `end` for the first line `<% show = @profile.shows.last %>`?

Comment: No, you don't have to include <% end %>, because it's not a loop or other form of block, it's a one-line assignment. The one that is there closes the <% if %> block.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .blank? method for the global variable you're trying to tell if it's empty. If its an array or hash. Use .nil? If its supposed to be anything else.